# Ionic / Capacitor Plugin: why is a method not being called?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm developing a plugin to handle bluetooth classic communication; everything seems to work fine, except for the write function. It looks like the method is not implemented, although the function is written both in the definitions.ts file and in the Plugin.java file

```java
    @PluginMethod
    public void write(PluginCall call) {
        call.unimplemented("not yet working");
    }
```

If I execute the app on an android device and try to call the write function, nothing happens: looking at the logs yelds this:

```
2023-07-25 09:29:54.887  8624-8624  AutofillManager         io.ionic.starter                     V  requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null
2023-07-25 09:29:54.976  8624-8624  Capacitor/Plugin        io.ionic.starter                     V  To native (Capacitor plugin): callbackId: 131962550, pluginId: Bluetooth, methodName: write
2023-07-25 09:29:54.976  8624-8624  Capacitor               io.ionic.starter                     V  callback: 131962550, pluginId: Bluetooth, methodName: write, methodData: {"message":"hello world"}
```

The definition.ts file looks like this:

```
  init(): Promise<void>;
  checkPermissions(): Promise<PermissionStatus>;
  requestPermissions(): Promise<PermissionStatus>;
  startListening(): Promise<boolean>;
  stopListening(): Promise<boolean>;
  write(data: {message: string}): Promise<boolean>;
```

All other methods work fine, but write does not.
Anyone ever had this kind of problem?

Edit: tried rebuilding, unlinking and relinking, changing the method's name, but nothing seems to work.

Edit2: started using breakpoints on the Bridge files for Capacitor. All methods are being registered with the plugin, but the only that is not getting invoked is `write`.

Comment: Do you have the github repo for this plugin in order to test and replicate the issue?